# Continuity of probability measure dependent on a measure-parameter

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Consider an arbitrary probability spaces $\Omega$ and $S$. Let $\mu$ be an arbitrary probability measure on $S$ and let $\mathbb P^\mu$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$ for every $\mu$ on $S$. Let $\mu_t$ also be a probability measure on $S$ for each $t\in[0,\infty)$ and $\nu$ also a probability on $S$. Suppose $\mu_t\to\nu$ as $t\to\infty$ in the usual sense of weak convergence, i.e. $\int_S f(s)\mu_t(ds)\to \int_S f(s)\nu(ds)$ as $t\to\infty$ for bounded continuous funcitons $f$. Let $B$ be some event in $\Omega$. Do I have that $\mathbb P^{\mu_t}(B)\rightarrow \mathbb P^{\nu}(B)$ a $t\to\infty$? Intuitively, it seems that this should work.

The setup I envision is that we are randomly choosing an element $s\in S$ and that the probability of event $B$ depends on what $s$ we choose. Let $\mathbb P^{\delta_s}(B)$ be the probability of event $B$ if we choose $s\in S$.

My thinking is that:
$$\mathbb P^{\nu}(B)=\int_S\mathbb P^{\delta_s}(B) \nu(ds)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_S\mathbb P^{\delta_s}(B) \mu_t(ds)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb P^{\mu_t}(B).$$

Please let me know if this is not clear, and I can probably refine my text or come up with a more concrete example to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the case only if $B$ is a continuity set of $\nu$, that is if $\nu(\partial B) = 0$.

See the portmanteau theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures

Your "proof" is false, the map $s \mapsto \mathbb P^{\delta_s}(B)$ (which you should really write $1_B(s)$, the indicator function) is not bounded continuous on $S$.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is correct. I suppose my problem is that I don't have an intuitive sense of what an event in the continuity set generally "looks like". So $1_B(s)$ is certainly bounded, but I suppose $B$ being a continuity set for $\nu$ is equivalent to $1_B(s)$  being continuous? If so, then the puzzle is slowly coming together for me.

Comment: No no no. $1_B$ is never continuous except in pathological cases. But the portmanteau theorem tells you that you can extract much more from weak convergence than just bounded continuous functions, in particular convergence of probabilities when the event is a continuity set of the limit.

Comment: Secondly, let me give you an example. Assume $\nu$ is a continuous measure (no atoms) on $\mathbb R$, like the Gaussian distribution. Then segments are continuity sets because $\nu(\partial [a,b]) = \nu(\{a,b\}) = 0$. Then $\mu_t([a,b]) \to \nu([a,b])$.

Comment: On the other hands, take $\mu_t$ to be Gaussian with mean zero and variance $1/t$. then $\mu_t \to \delta_0$. But $0=\mu_t(\{0\}) \not \to \delta_0(\{0\}) = 1$. Can you see why the continuity set requirement is not verified here ?

Comment: To conclude, the point is that weak convergence allows to wiggle mass around a little, which causes problems with the boundary of sets.

Comment: I see the logical mistake I made there regarding my (erroneously) concluding the indicator should be continuous. Thanks! You examples are very helpful! I believe I now see that this is really just a straightforward implication of the Portmanteau theorem - though I hope to study the proof of that theorem carefully so that I really understand it